# How to use background image with tailwind in next.js?

Tags: css, next.js, jsx, background-image, tailwind-css

I have a background image in the public folder named `bg.png`

In the index.js page of the pages folder I want to use that image as a background image

I have install tailwind following the documentation of their official website.

I have already tried this, but it doesn't work.

import BG from "../public/bg.png";

```
return (
  <div
    className="bg-scroll"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${BG})`,
      height: "972px",
    }}
  >
  </div>
)
```

It doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 12):

When you have assets in a public folder no need to define all the exact path.

```
  <div
   className="bg-scroll"
   style={{
    backgroundImage: `url('/bg.png')`,
     height: "972px",
    }}
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is that you can define the image in `tailwind.config.js` file as lke this

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'my_bg_image' : "url('../public/bg.png')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Then use it in the component as `bg-my_bg_img` directly. No need to import image.

```
return (
  <div
    className="bg-scroll bg-my_bg_image h-[972px]"
  >
  </div>
)
```

Comment: In Next.js 13.5 this produces this url `url(webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin//_next/static/media/thumbnail-background.29d36fbf.svg)` which doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can do it all with Tailwind. You don't need to `import` the image either.

```
return (
  <div
    className="bg-scroll bg-[url('/bg.png')] h-[972px]"
  >
  </div>
)
```